# How to add column with accumulations of certain values from another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Here is my table:

```
     date           id  action     value
    2021-09-02      aa  income      500
    2021-09-02      aa  spending    500
    2021-09-02      aa  spending    45
    2021-09-03      aa  income      30
    2021-09-03      aa  income      30
    2021-09-03      aa  spending    25
    2021-09-04      b1  income      100
    2021-09-05      b1  income      500
    2021-09-05      b1  spending    500
    2021-09-05      b1  spending    45
    2021-09-06      b1  income      30
    2021-09-06      b1  income      30
    2021-09-07      b1  spending    25
```

As you see there is two types of actions "income" and "spending". What I want is to add column with accumulation of "value" at each moment for each of my id. And after each action "income" it must increase by value of that "income" and when there is "spending" it must decrease by value of that decrease.  So result must look like this:

```
     date           id  action     value    saved 
    2021-09-02      aa  income      500      0
    2021-09-02      aa  spending    400      500
    2021-09-02      aa  spending    40       100
    2021-09-03      aa  income      30       60     
    2021-09-03      aa  income      30       90
    2021-09-03      aa  spending    25       120
    2021-09-04      b1  income      100      0
    2021-09-05      b1  income      500      100
    2021-09-05      b1  spending    500      600
    2021-09-05      b1  spending    45       100
    2021-09-06      b1  income      30       55
    2021-09-06      b1  income      30       85
    2021-09-07      b1  spending    25       115
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first negate `value` based on `action`, then groupby `id` and finally, since you want to start at value 0, shift the rows by one on the groups. Finally get the cumsum:

```
df.value.where(df.action=='income', -df.value).groupby(df.id).shift().groupby(df.id).cumsum()
```

---

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ('2021-09-02', '2021-09-02', '2021-09-02', '2021-09-03', '2021-09-03', '2021-09-03', '2021-09-04', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06', '2021-09-06', '2021-09-07'), 'id': ('aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'b1', 'b1', 'b1', 'b1', 'b1', 'b1', 'b1'), 'action': ('income', 'spending', 'spending', 'income', 'income', 'spending', 'income', 'income', 'spending', 'spending', 'income', 'income', 'spending'), 'value': map(int, ('500', '500', '45', '30', '30', '25', '100', '500', '500', '45', '30', '30', '25'))})
>>> df
          date  id    action  value
0   2021-09-02  aa    income    500
1   2021-09-02  aa  spending    400
2   2021-09-02  aa  spending     40
3   2021-09-03  aa    income     30
4   2021-09-03  aa    income     30
5   2021-09-03  aa  spending     25
6   2021-09-04  b1    income    100
7   2021-09-05  b1    income    500
8   2021-09-05  b1  spending    500
9   2021-09-05  b1  spending     45
10  2021-09-06  b1    income     30
11  2021-09-06  b1    income     30
12  2021-09-07  b1  spending     25
>>> df.value.where(df.action=='income', -df.value).groupby(df.id).shift().groupby(df.id).cumsum()
>>> df
          date  id    action  value  saved
0   2021-09-02  aa    income    500    0.0
1   2021-09-02  aa  spending    400  500.0
2   2021-09-02  aa  spending     40  100.0
3   2021-09-03  aa    income     30   60.0
4   2021-09-03  aa    income     30   90.0
5   2021-09-03  aa  spending     25  120.0
6   2021-09-04  b1    income    100    0.0
7   2021-09-05  b1    income    500  100.0
8   2021-09-05  b1  spending    500  600.0
9   2021-09-05  b1  spending     45  100.0
10  2021-09-06  b1    income     30   55.0
11  2021-09-06  b1    income     30   85.0
12  2021-09-07  b1  spending     25  115.0
```

Comment: why its 220 in column saved in 7th row? it must be 100

Comment: @french_fries My apologies, I edited with corrected code, I just forgot a `groupby` after the `shift`